# Bash script to create and delete a file N times

Tags: bash

Simple question - is there a quick bash script or one-liner that will repeatedly create a file with a random name (no content necessary) and then subsequently delete the file it just created?

Comment: Which part do you need help with? Doing an action repeatedly, creating a file with a random name, or deleting a file?

Comment: N files with the _same_ random name, or is the file name allowed to be different each time?

Comment: @Ezphares each file name should be different

Comment: Does something like `for n in {1..10}; do (F=$(mktemp) && rm "$F"); done` work for you (replacing 10 with your desired N)?

Comment: Yep, that's perfect. Thanks! I didn't know about `mktemp`, and I'm not familiar with bash so that is a helpful snippet.

Comment: I gotta ask -- *why*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mktemp` that should give almost a random filename and execute it count times:

```
seq 10|xargs -l sh -c 'rm "$(mktemp)"'
```

Alternatively you could use `$RANDOM`:

```
seq 10|xargs -l sh -c 'a=$RANDOM;touch $a;rm $a'
```